# How to know if I installed Dart or Flutter in my Computer?

Tags: shell, flutter, dart, prompt

How to know if I install Dart or Flutter in my Windows 10 PC?

is there any Code I write in 'Command prompt' or 'Power Shell' to see if I installed Dart or Flutter?

and How to Update them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check installed version of Flutter SDK, run:

```dart
flutter --version
```

To check installed version of Dart SDK, run:

```dart
dart --version
```

Answer (score 1):

For flutter run this command `flutter --version`

Comment: C:\>flutter --version
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory in which you have pasted the flutter folder, in my case the path is **C:\src\flutter**, and inside that folder search for the file named `flutter_console`. After that open the file and run the command `flutter doctor`. The execution will take some time and on completion, it will show all the issues found.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue run the command

`flutter upgrade --force`

and this will override your pre-installed flutter version by the newest version in the directory you installed flutter. To complete the process basis on your internet speed it may take few minutes. After finished installation run those command

`flutter --version` & `dart --version`

Then you will see output of the versions in the console.